# Filter based on threshold of missing values percentage by column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I've seen various posts calculating % missing values by column ... How can I filter a data frame to contain only those variables that have below a given percentage of missing values? E.g., filtering for variables with under 80% missing values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a = c(rep(NA, 10), 11),
                 b = c(NA, 1:10))

df %>%
  select(where(~sum(is.na(.x))/length(.x) < 0.8))

    b
1  NA
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   5
7   6
8   7
9   8
10  9
11 10
```

Comment: THank you deschen! Is there an advantage to doing it the above vs. below? I just came across this approach that also seems to work? 
colSums(is.na(df2)) / nrow(df2)    

df2_test <- df2[, colSums(is.na(df2)) / nrow(df2) < 0.8]

Comment: That‘s just personal taste. Pick whatever solution works best for you. Personally, I usually prefer a tidyverse approach.